# Change value of all cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write code that reformats text messages in an excel file using VBA. One column has the dates each text was sent/received. I need to change this column to say "Day 1", "Day 2", instead. So for example, 11/3/19 would be "Day 1" 11/3/19 would be "Day 1" 11/4/19 would be "Day 2" 11/6/19 would be "Day 4"

To do this, I want to subtract each date by the first date and add 1. I can do this per individual cell:

```
Sub Days()
Range("M2").Value = "Day " + CStr(Range("E2").Value - Range("E2").Value + 1)
Range("M3").Value = "Day " + CStr(Range("E3").Value - Range("E2").Value + 1)
Range("M4").Value = "Day " + CStr(Range("E4").Value - Range("E2").Value + 1)
End Sub
```

I want it done to every cell in column E. This was my attempt:

```
Sub Days()
Columns("M:M").Value = "Day " + CStr(Columns("E:E").Value - Range("E2").Value + 1)
(End Sub)
```

How would I adjust the code to make it work?

Comment: Add some screenshots of sample data you have now and what you want to have in result

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak - sample data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162091/how-to-reference-a-range-of-cells-that-always-changes) :-)

Comment: Why vba?  Just put `="Day " & E2 - $E$2 + 1` in M2 and copy down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do the full column.  Find the last cell with data in column E then use Evaluate:

```
Sub Days()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Dim lstRow As Long
        lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("M2:M" & lstRow) = .Evaluate("INDEX(""Day "" & E2:E" & lstRow & " - E2 + 1,)")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted for the .Evaluate step - I thought about it but was too lazy :-). Plus I kinda copied your formula, so there's that. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want this to be VBA, here's one solution, leveraging the formula already provided in comments:

```
Sub Days()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("M2:M" & lastRow).Formula = "=""Day "" & E2 - $E$2 + 1"
        .Range("M2:M" & lastRow).Value = .Range("M2:M" & lastRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you accept the other answer actually? It is better, plus I used Scott's formula in my answer. He deserves the credit.

Comment: I made the change